# How to bias an absolute sine wave in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am using the below python code so as to bias an absolute sine wave. I would like to have only the crest part of the wave and not the trough part even after positive biasing.Here I am unable achieve continuous crest signal after positive biasing. Can any one help me in this?

Usage: Keeping the input signals above the threshold even during dynamic shift of threshold.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Bias=5;
x=np.linspace(-20,20,1000);
y=np.abs(np.sin(x)+Bias);
#Bias=np.zeros_like(x); # This is not working

y[(y<=Bias)]= Bias + y # This is not working
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: The description is not really clear. Could you add a picture of what you want your sine to look like vs. what you are getting?

Comment: `y[y<=Bias] += Bias` ?

Comment: and 'by not working' I assume you mean 'raises an exception'.  You should include the full traceback in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a litle bit unclear what you are asking... Maybe you want to try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
Bias=5;

x = np.linspace(-20, 20, 1000);
y = np.abs(np.sin(x))
y = y + Bias  

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

### or this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
Bias=5;

x=np.linspace(-20,20,1000);
y=np.abs(np.sin(x) + Bias);

y[(y<=Bias)]= Bias

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]